# Trouble with java vlcj 1.2.2 RTSP client example (Mac OSX 10.6)

Tags: java, rtsp, vlcj

I'm trying to get their tutorial code running to connect to a rtsp stream from my webcam and display the feed on a JFrame.  I modified their example code to make a simple client rtsp viewer. When I specify the directory location in the playMedia method,  I can play mp3s, mpegs, avi's just fine.

e.g. mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("/Volumes/dl/The Lord Of The Rings - The Two Towers/The Lord Of The Rings - The Two Towers - Disc 1.mp4"); //works

When I enter a working RTSP mrl, it breaks.  It works in the VLC standalone application running live555.  With this client code, I just get a black screen.

```
    import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
    import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
    import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
    import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
    import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.mrl.RtspMrl;

    public class Tutorial1B {

        private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            if (com.sun.jna.Platform.isMac()) {
                final String jnaLibraryPath = System.getProperty("jna.library.path");
                final StringBuilder newJnaLibraryPath = new StringBuilder(jnaLibraryPath != null ? (jnaLibraryPath + ":") : "");
                newJnaLibraryPath.append("/Users/Huy/Downloads/vlc-vlckit-x86_64-20120131-2049/VLCKit/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/lib");
                System.setProperty("jna.library.path", newJnaLibraryPath.toString());
            }   



            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
             public void run() {
              new Tutorial1B();
             }
             });
            }

    private Tutorial1B() {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("HUY vlcj");

       mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

       frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);

       frame.setLocation(100, 100);
       frame.setSize(1050, 600);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       String mrl = new RtspMrl().host("192.168.0.191")
                       .port(554)
                       .path("/live/ch01_0/")
                       .value();    

    //mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("/Volumes/dl/The Lord Of The Rings - The Two Towers/The Lord Of The Rings - The Two Towers - Disc 1.mp4");
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mrl);
       }    
    }
```

I'm out of ideas, and I scoured this site and their tutorials for examples to no avail.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What libVLC version are you using to bind to VLCJ 1.2.2? Also, what is the expected MRL string: is it "rtsp://192.168.0.191:554/live/ch01_0/"? Maybe, you can try "rtsp://@192.168.0.191:554/live/ch01_0/". Don't ask me why ampersand is needed if it works; I also find it is very strange...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried multiple stable builds of the vlc releases for 64 bit releases including the latest.  This code works when I compiled it in Windows when I execute it with -Djna.library.path="xxxx\VideoLan\VLC".  I've tested this mrl in the VLC application itself.  I suspect this may be a vlcj problem.

Comment: Have you tested VLCJ running on Java JVM in 64-bit when using libVLC 64-bit version? Otherwise, you have to use 32-bit version for everything...

Answer (score 0):

Hi It is working well for me on Snow Leopard.

For the MRL you have to specify as @ee said.